# Dotnet run - Can't find a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio for exercises from Code Academy's virtual console.

I open C# file in Visual Studio (2022 version). When entering 'dotnet run' in Powershell, it returns:

'Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in C/Users/(username)/source/repos, or pass the path using --project.'

What I don't get is, the .cs file is there, despite terminal saying it isn't.

Thank you and happy holidays

Comment: you need a `.csproj`

Comment: `dotnet new project`

Comment: Thank you! Some progress: started new project and saw it created .csproj file in same location as .cs file. Got same error message when I opened powershell and typed 'dotnet run', but I was able to debug with green 'start' button (F5) on toolbar.

Comment: Hi, if my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

When using dotnet run, you need to pay attention to the following points:

1. The dotnet run command can only be used to run executable files and cannot be used to run class libraries.
2. Like general applications, console or form applications must have an entry point Main.
3. Before using the dotnet run command, make sure that the dotnet build command has been executed so that the executable file can be generated.

In addition, you can also just use the button to run the program that comes with Visual Studio, and Visual Studio will automatically compile the program for you. Or you can directly press F5 to quickly start

[image]